# confirmpayment is assigned a value but never used

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodemon, strip

when i fill in the card details and the rest, when i click pay, i get error message,i dont know if its a code issue or setting that my vs code is flagging my confirmpayment as "confirmpayment is assign a value but its never used. its meant to nagivate to the success page. what should i do? here is my code

```
 const confirmPayment = await stripe.confirmPayment({elements,confirmParams: {
        // Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the PaymentIntent is confirmed
        return_url: "http://localhost:3000/checkout-success",
      },
      redirect: "if_required",
    })
    .then((result) =>{
        // ok - paymentIntent bad - error
        if (result.error) {
            toast.error(result.error.message)
            setMessage(result.error.message)
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Well, do you ever use the `confirmPayment` variable?  If not then that's exactly what the message is telling you.  If you don't need it then you can safely remove it.

Comment: What error do you get when you click? Your title looks like a warning from a linter, not a runtime error.